# How to mute whole lobby on voice chat in gta online?

Tags: ps4, grand-theft-auto-online

I always create a private party to mute them but is there a way other than creating a private party?

Note: I tried changing voice chat to "no-one" in the interaction menu but it doesn't turn it off.

Comment: I used to do this, cant you change your voice chat options to 'only friends'?

Comment: I generally use 'only friends' as well, but I have noticed a bug that in the loading screens you can still hear voices (crazy). I don't know if this is fixed or not, but that was the only time I would hear them otherwise.

Comment: Yeah, that option is to do exactly what you're asking for, but during session loading it's ignored.  The game is rife with bugs so I don't expect something like this to be a priority.  Your idea of creating a party is the only solid solution to this.

Comment: On the PC (and I didn't check this on the PS4), on options there is a whole option tab just for configuring voice chat, volume, volume of the rest of the game while someone is speaking and you can turn it entirely off altogether, I believe and expect that PS4 has this same tab too.

Comment: A shitty workaround could be plugging a dummy headphone pin on the controller and setting the PS4 to output voice chat to the headphones only, it's a shitty and lame workaround but, meh.

Answer (score 1):

Press and hold the <kbd>PS4</kbd> button to bring up the quick menu. From there, go into "Sound", and select 'Disable chat audio'.

That should disable it entirely.